# not able to do routing properly in page.js

Tags: javascript, url-routing, single-page-application, page.js

I am using `page.js` for routing in a `Single Page Application`. For testing purpose, I am using `npm http-server`.

I am not able to do routing. I am not sure what I am missing. following is my code:

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>test page!</title>
  <script src="/js/libs/page.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  this is body of test
  <a href="/test">Simple test</a>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/routes.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

routes.js

```
function initRoutes () {
  var testRoutes = {
    test : function (context, next) {
      alert("testing");

      if(next){
        next();
      }
    },
    test2 : function (context, next) {
      alert("I am jon snow, I know nothing.");
    }
  };
  page.base('/');

  page('/', testRoutes.test);
  page('/test', testRoutes.test2);
  page('/two-args', testRoutes.test, testRoutes.test2);
  page();
}
initRoutes();
```

from my `http-server`, I am accessing http://0.0.0.0:8081. I am getting an test as `alert`, but I am not getting the `alert` for route http://0.0.0.0:8081/test.

I am not sure what I am missing. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Had the same problem, did you reach to a solution?

Comment: @dimitrismistriotis try to comment `page.base()`. that worked for me